# Surface of revolution volume

Tags: geometry

How to find volume of toroid with rounded ribs? The problem I've faced is what radius should I use when I find width of small piece  before integrating it from 0 to 2pi. What distance to choose: to the diameter or circle edge, or should I find the line which separate semicircle on the even parts (A=B).[image: (A=B)]

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. One simplification you can do is working out the volume of the whole shape (red+green sphere) and then subtracting the volume of the green cylinder with curved end caps. You can split that step into three integrals (where the first is equal to the third).

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you find the volume of the hole and subtract it from the volume of the sphere. To find the volume of the hole you need to points of intersection of the circle with the line y-h. The middle part of the hole is just a cylinder. For the corners have two integrals to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relationship between the height of the hole and the radius of sphere when the two volumes are equal.
[image]